# How to use Hoeffding Inequality?

Tags: statistics, machine-learning

I am new to Hoeffding Inequality and can someone kindly explain to me how to use it?

I need to solve the following problem. If $\mu = 0.9$, use Hoeffding Inequality to bound the probability that a sample of 10 marbles will have $k \leq 0.1$. $\mu$ refers to the probability of red marbles in a bin of red and green marbles and $k$ refers to the fraction of red marbles within the sample

Hoeffding Inequality is given as $P(|k - \mu| > \epsilon) \leq 2e^{-2\epsilon^2 N}$ for any $\epsilon > 0$.

I can't relate binomial distribution to Hoeffding Inequality.